# What determines whether multiple highlighted files in Finder show in the same Get Info window?

Tags: finder

I'll often highlight a bunch of files in Finder to find their collective size with Cmd+I. Sometimes the Get Info window shows the pooled size in a single window, but other times it'll open 40 separate Get Info windows. What determines when this happens?

(I've since learned that [other key combinations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62589/21351) will always show the highlighted items' collective size, but when does Cmd+I alone act one way instead of the aforementioned other?)