# How can I decrease the maximum number of files where Get Info will open multiple windows?

Tags: finder

Is there some plist I can edit to decrease the number of files that Finder's Get Info function will open separate info windows for?

The number of Get Info windows that will open simultaneously is [THIRTY-FIVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE33D.jpg). The windows slowly appear one at a time, and once they finally finish appearing I have to close them all one at a time. Pure madness, and whoever chose the default value for this feature should go outside and think about what they've done.

If I get info on thirty-six files, it finally automatically consolidates them into a [**Summary Info** window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO4yp.jpg) I would like to change this threshold of 36 to something reasonable, like 4.

I know about the [shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/62590/42863) to open the Inspector and Summary Info windows, however sometimes I accidentally forget to hold Option or Control, and I would like to eliminate the possibility of this happening by accident.

A satisfactory alternate solution would be if there were a way to make Get Info always open a Summary Info window instead of opening separate file info windows.

MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) running 10.10.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for 10.7.5-10.9.5 the assumption that the number of *Get Info* windows is restricted to 35 is wrong.

Instead the screen resolution and the size of the *Get Info* window seem to be the restricting factors. Using a 1920x1200 px monitor I get 6 windows in a row and 12 rows (= 72 windows).

Trying to get the info on 73 objects and more a summarizing *Get Info* window will open.

Apparently there is no simple hidden numerical threshold of simultaneously opening *Get Info* windows.

To simply have an identical behavior for <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> map <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> for the Finder.app with a key remapping app.

If you don't want to use a remapping app use System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and create custom Finder shortcuts: *Get Info* -> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (to disable <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) or Get Info -> <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and Show Inspector -> <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to swap the shortcuts of *Get Info* and *Show Inspector*. The same applies to *Get Summary Info* (with a different shortcut of course) if you prefer to change that one.

---

To quickly close all *Get Info* windows hit <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> or for some system versions alt-click on the close button of one of the windows. All other non-*Get Info* windows will also be closed though.